# Using an article in "the rest of [the] thesis"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article

I am describing the structure of a thesis. In it, I have:

> Chapter X provides the required details to comprehend the rest of
> the thesis

OR

> Chapter X provides the required details to comprehend the rest of
> thesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say

> ...the rest of **the** thesis...

because you are describing a specific thesis and would use "the" rather than "a" in this case. In any case, unless you're writing informally, you would use an article (for the same reason you said "provides **the** required details because you are talking about a specific set of required details).